# Problems with C^b C^[arrow key] in tmux through a ssh session from a mintty terminal

Tags: ssh, cygwin, tmux

I have a server that I ssh to from Windows 7 using Cygwin+mintty. On the server I attach to a tmux session. So far so good, but when I try to change the tmux layout using **C^b [arrow]** and **C^b M^[arrow]** I get problems.

Some times it works, as in the layout changes but most of the time the code for the key pressing is printed in the shell like this:
*user@server> [1;5D*
This is for C^b C^left. Usually it works the first time but all the following tries will print the code instead. So is there some way I can fix this for Cygwin? (as I don't have this problem when I ssh from a linux machine).

Comment: Could you try press `C^b ESC [arrow]`?

Comment: This works like a charm, sad for the extra key press but as long as it works...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

azat's comment solved my problem.